# Print attribute of last dynamic v-for loop element

Tags: vue.js

in a loop with Vue how do I print only the text and time of the last message?

this is the structure:
data:{

```
    contatti: [
        
        {
            nome: 'Matteo',
            immagine: '_1',
            visibile: true,
            messaggi: [
                {
                    data: '10/01/2020 15:30:55',
                    ora:   '15:30',
                    testo: 'Hai portato a spasso il cane?',
                    stato: 'inviato',
                    visualizzato: true
                },
                {
                    data: '10/01/2020 15:50:00',
                    ora:   '15:50',
                    testo: 'Ricordati di dargli da mangiare',
                    stato: 'inviato',
                    visualizzato: true
                },
                {
                    data: '10/01/2020 16:15:22',
                    ora:   '16:15',
                    testo: 'Tutto fatto!',
                    stato: 'ricevuto'
                }
            ],
        },
```

---

```
                <ul class="px-3 list-group list-group-flush">

                  <li class="list-group-item flex-row " v-for="(contatto, index) in contatti" @click="selezioneContatto(index)">
                  
                    <img :src="'./assets/img/avatar' + contatto.immagine + '.jpg'" class="img-fluid avatar rounded-circle me-3 py-2" alt="">
                    <span>{{contatto.nome}}</span>
                    <span v-for="(messaggio, index) in contatto.messaggi[index]" >{{messaggio.testo}}</span>
                    
                  </li>
                  
                </ul>
```

so it prints them all I would like to print only the last text and the last hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a custom method:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: () => ({
    contatti: [  
      {
        nome: 'Name 1',
        immagine: '_1',
        visibile: true,
        messaggi: [
          { data: '10/01/2020 15:30:55', ora: '15:30', testo: 'Test 1-a', stato: 'inviato', visualizzato: true },
          { data: '10/01/2020 16:15:22', ora: '16:15', testo: 'Test 1-b', stato: 'ricevuto' }
        ]
      },
      {
        nome: 'Name 2',
        immagine: '_1',
        visibile: true,
        messaggi: [
          { data: '10/01/2020 16:15:22', ora: '16:15', testo: 'Test 2-a', stato: 'ricevuto' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    getMostRecentMessageTesto(index) {
      const { messaggi = [] } = this.contatti[index];
      const lastItem = messaggi.length > 0 ? messaggi[messaggi.length - 1] : {};
      return lastItem.testo;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="({ nome, lastItem }, index) in contatti" :key="index">
    {{nome}} {{getMostRecentMessageTesto(index)}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer. However, for what it's worth, `Array.prototype.map` returns a completely new array, which I assume could be quite expensive in specific circumstances - particularly if the source array is very large. Instead, one could also create a method such as `getMostRecentMessage(contatti)` which can be invoked for each item in `v-for`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers but I solved it by setting a condition

v-for="(item, key) in array" v-if="key + 1 === array.length">

Answer (score 0):

You can run directly js code in html but just for 1 line.
I suggest you create a function for this, for clean code.

```
      {{contatti[0].messaggi[contatti[0].messaggi.length-1].data}}
      {{contatti[0].messaggi[contatti[0].messaggi.length-1].testo}}
```

Comment: Above I express the code in an even cleaner way